# When do I use "are" instead of "is" with a measurement?

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number, numbers

When writing measurements or time, do you use the plural form "are" or the singular form "is"?

For example:

> There [is/are] 12 inches in a foot.
>
> There [is/are] 12 months in a year.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U Ananymous.  Your question should be asked at ELL, our sister site for those who are learning the English language.  BTW, it's "there are".

Comment: One question at a time, please.

Answer (score 2):

You use "is" for singular words and "are" for plurals.

**Examples:**

> There [is/**are**] 12 inches in a foot.

You need to use "are" because "inches" is **plural**; there is more than one inch.

> There [**is**/are] 1 inch for every 2.54 centimetres.

You need to use "is" here because "inch" is **singular**; there is only one inch.

The same rule is followed for your second example:

> There [is/**are**] 12 months in a year.
>
> There [**is**/are] 1 month until your birthday.

Comment: In spoken words though, you tend to hear "There's 12 inches in a foot", which is maybe where OP's confusion stems from. This isn't grammatically correct, but still used because it's easier/faster to pronounce "there's" instead of "there are".

Comment: @Flater It is interesting that, isn't it?

Comment: Odd, but understandable. Spoken language has the added effect of relying on physical body movement, and it will over time find 'shortcuts' that allow for a fluid speech pattern. It's somewhat understandable that a spoken phrase and a written phrase evolve differently, as one might evolve to be easier to pronounce, and the other to be easier to know the spelling of.

Comment: @Flater It's funny you mention it because I just answered a question on the use of "how's" as "how has". Just as long as people don't say "could of"!

Comment: Actually, the ones that get me the most annoyed are words that are phonetically completely different, yet used for their how close their spelling is. "Defiantly" (where "definitely" was needed) is the archetypical example of this. And I used to love "defiantly" :(

Comment: Today's youth routinely use *[defanitely](http://momentofdouche.blogspot.com/2006/02/defanitely-douche.html?m=1)*. I'm not sure the connection with "defiantly." @Flater

Comment: More specifically, you use **is** for exactly one of something, and **are** for every other number, including negative numbers, zero, decimal values less than one, or decimal values beginning with one.

Answer (score 2):

> There are twelve inches in a foot.   There are twelve months in a year.

Here, "are" makes sense.   The inches and months are individual and countable.

> Twelve inches is big enough.   Twelve months is long enough.

Here, "is" makes sense.   The inches or months indicate a singular measurement.   It's one given length or one given duration that is sufficient.

In the first example, we could say "twelve individual inches" or "twelve separate inches" without changing the meaning of the sentence.   We cannot sensibly say "individual" or "separate" in the second example.   The subjects there are one continuous twelve-inch length and one continuous twelve-month duration.

Answer (score 1):

A priori, which one to choose depends on your point of view: Are *12 inches / 12 months* plurals or are they measurements?

> There are 12 inches in a foot. (Last time I counted them, it was still true.)
>
> There is [a length of] 12 inches in a foot. (Last time I measured a foot, this statement was correct up to an error < 0.5%.)
>
> There are 12 months in a year. (I love every one of them.)
>
> There is [a duration of] 12 months in a year. (If you count February as a full month. If we take a month to be 30.5 days, there is only about 11.97 months in a year.)

However, in English prescriptive grammar there is a tendency to regard such singulars where a plural would be more straightforward as errors, and even to treat measurements as plurals when this makes no sense. For instance, those who subscribe to the prescriptive rule that since *fewer* cannot be used for uncountable quantities, *less* cannot be used for countables, tend to use *fewer* even when it gives the wrong impression, as in "I live fewer than 2 kilometres from the station". (Technically this means that I live 0 kilometres or 1 kilometre from the station, but it is more likely meant to describe a distance strictly between 1 and 2 kilometres.)

Therefore, even though the variants with *is* occur in natural speech by native speakers, written English usually has *are*, and this is generally considered the only correct option.

(I am not a native speaker of English. In my native German, the equivalent of the variant with *are* is *definitely* the only correct one, even in colloquial speech. That's why I have paid some attention to the different situation in English.)